# AsyncTask doesn't receive cancel

Tags: android, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

I'm facing a little issue with my `AsyncTask`. 
I run the asynctask in this way:

```
myTask = new myTask();

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    // same as onquerychange
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                        if (myTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ||
                                myTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
                            myTask.cancel(true);
                        }
                        myTask.execute(context, s);
                    } else {
                        myTask.execute(context, "emptyquery");
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Once i type the second letter i keep getting: `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)

So i assume it doesn't get cancelled. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You are invoking asynctask multiple times

Comment: No need to cancel thread

Comment: i saw that, but I'm calling myTask.cancel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute the same `AsyncTask` more than once. You'll have to instantiate it before executing it each time, e.g.:

```
myTask = new myTask();
myTask.execute(context, s);
```

Of course you can then remove the initialization at the beginning.

For stopping and restarting, use:

```
myTaks.cancel(true);
myTask = new myTask();
myTask.execute(context, s);
```

Even though you cancel the `AsyncTask`, you cannot use it again.

Comment: Yeah i know, but i would like to execute the task only once... so if for example i type fast in my searchbar: a - b - c - d I will have 4 running task... i would like only one on the last search query! possible?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `myTask.cancel();` the AsyncTask try to stop the thread. to force that, you can check if the task has been cancelled with:

```
if(isCancelled()){
   return null;
}
```

inside the `doInBackground` and block it by yourself. Otherwise the status of the AsyncTask has been checked before to call the `onPostExecute`. in this way if you call the `cancel()` you are sure that no value is returned. check the doc here: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

and anyway: an AsyncTask can be executed only once. you have to instantiate another AsyncTask if you have to run it again.